# jQuery show() method is not working on Chrome and IE browers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am showing a progress loader on my webpage when there are some processing going on in the background task. The problem I am facing is that the div which contains progress loader always stays "display : none " on Chrome and IE browser. However it works fine on FF and Safari.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="progressIndicatorBackground">
  <div id="progressIndicator">
    <img src="/cms/images/icons/progressIndicator.gif" alt="Loading...">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#progressIndicatorBackground, #preLoaderBackground {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9000;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

JS function for showing and hiding progress loader

```
function progressIndicator(value) {

    if(value) {
        $("#progressIndicatorBackground").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#progressIndicatorBackground").hide();
    }
}
```

On several occasion I am calling the progressIndicator function. For e.g. In one of the page I am  calling the function (This is just an example function I am using in my web app. There are other functions as well where I am calling progressIndicator function in the same way)

```
racingSubCategoryBindClick: function(id, parentId) {

        if ($('#'+id).css('display') != 'none') {
            $("#"+id).unbind();
            $("#"+id).live('click', function() {

                // Make all the rest of the group not active, not only this active
                $('.' + $(this).attr('class') +'.active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');

                progressIndicator(true);

                var menuId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id'), day;
                if (menuId.indexOf(days.today) != -1) day = days.today
                else if (menuId.indexOf(days.tomorrow) != -1) day = days.tomorrow
                else day = days.upcoming;

                $.when(ajaxCalls.fetchEventsForCategory(id, parentId, day)).done(function (eventsMap) {

                    // There are no events
                    if (eventsMap.events.length == 0 || eventsMap.events[0].markets.length == 0) {
                        $('#mainError').show();
                        $('div.main').hide();
                    }

                    else {
                        $('#mainError').hide();

                        $('#'+id).addClass('active');

                        var events = eventsMap.events;

                        // If there are events
                        if (events.length > 0) {

                            var firstActive = racingNavigation.drawAllRaceNumbers(events);
                            racingNavigation.drawRaceView(events, firstActive);
                            // if 1st time and no next selections on the right
                            if ($('#tabaside').css('display') == 'none') racingNavigation.drawNextRaces(false, true, numberOfNextRaces);
                            $('.racing_nextraces').hide()
                        }
                        $('div.main').show();
                    }
                });

                $('.rightmain').show();
                $('#racing_home').hide();

                progressIndicator(false);
            });
        }
    },
```

When the background task is in progress and I am fetching JSON data the progress indicator should be visible after calling progressIndicator(true) and as soon as the processing is completed the display attribute should be set to none as I am calling progressIndicator(false) after everything is done. But the status of progressIndicatorBackground is never set display : block on Chrome and IE.

P.S -> I am using latest version or Chrome and IE.

P.S.S -> I have tried modifying my function to but no luck. The problem still persist on Chrome and IE.

```
function progressIndicator(value) {

    if(value) {
        $("#progressIndicatorBackground").css("display", "block"); 
    }
    else {
        $("#progressIndicatorBackground").css("display", "none"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: check the `visibility` style also

Comment: value returns string or boolean please check

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle, by the looks of it you have the relevant code, creating a fiddle will speed things up.

Comment: .show() works on all browsers, however if the content you are showing is hidden too, then it will not show anything

Comment: I think your code always return false so it is hide

Comment: @sudhar It does return true otherwise it wouldn't be working on FF and Safari.

Comment: @mplungjan The content is not set to hidden. Infact there isn't any content inside the the progress loader. The duration of loader is only until the JSON fetching request is completed.

Comment: Your site loads too slow to test it. LiveAgentChat blocks the loading

Comment: @mplungjan I have disabled live chat agent now.

Comment: And google analytics. Shows the value of an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah I disabled that too.

Comment: I have a feeling that your readystate checker with an interval of 10 milliseconds may slow the whole thing down. I would reconsider the whole process. It took almost a minute to load the page and in the mean time I was completely in the dark

Comment: @mplungjan I have also attached a screenshot of Chrome debugger. As you can see while switched from one race to another the progressIndicatorBackground always stays to display:none while on FF it changes to display:block when there is any background processing is going on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51677/discussion-between-mplungjan-and-nish)

Comment: This may be Chrome overlay bug related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was because of using synchronous AJAX calls. It does freezes Chrome and IE and stop any other events to fire up.

Progress loader wasn't working because it was waiting for the synchronous ajax calls to finish loading the event.

Original AJAX call

```
fetchEventsForCategory: function (categoryId, parentId, day) {

        var to = (date.getTo(day) == null) ? '' : '&to=' + date.getTo(day);

        return $.ajax({
            url: "/billfold-api/betting/events",
            type: "POST",
            data: 'scid=' + categoryId + '&pcid=' + parentId + '&from=' + date.getFrom(day) + to,
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
        });
    },
```

Modified AJAX call with success callback

```
fetchEventsForCategory: function (categoryId, parentId, day) {
        var to = (date.getTo(day) == null) ? '' : '&to=' + date.getTo(day);

        return $.ajax({
            url: "/billfold-api/betting/events",
            type: "POST",
            data: 'scid=' + categoryId + '&pcid=' + parentId + '&from=' + date.getFrom(day) + to,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                progressIndicator(false);
            }
        });
    },
```

In my JS function where I was calling the progress loader. I removed `progressIndicator(false);`and instead put it under success function in my ajax call itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience `display:none` can make things buggy and should only be used as a last resort. Take a look at [this article](http://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/) here for alternatives. Also I found sometimes adding `:hidden` helps in making jquery show a hidden or `display:none` element. So for instance `$("#progressIndicatorBackground:hidden").show();` might get it to work.

Comment: Unfortunately adding $("#progressIndicatorBackground:hidden").show(); didn't work in my case. I made some changes in my code and posted another question. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366971/jquery-toggle-hide-show-chrome-overlay-bug