# jQuery toggle, hide, show - Chrome overlay bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This question is in continuation with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359314/jquery-show-method-is-not-working-on-chrome-and-ie-browers) question, which I have posted earlier today.

Chrome overlay bug link is [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345894)

Most of the details I have posted in my eartlier question (Link provided above). So After fiddling around with the code and with some help from one of the stackoverflow member we have come to the decision that the problem is not scripting related rather it is purely CSS issue on Chrome.

Here are 3 different versions of the same function I modified earlier

JS version 1 (Original) - Progress loader works on FF, Safari but not on Chrome and IE

```
function progressIndicator(value) {

    if(value) {
        $("#progressIndicatorBackground").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#progressIndicatorBackground").hide();
    }
}
```

JS version 2 - After applying Chrome overlay fix  - No luck, still the same problem.

```
function progressIndicator(value) {

    if(value) {
        $("#progressIndicatorBackground").show();
        var TmpHeigh = $("#progressIndicatorBackground").css('height');
        $("#progressIndicatorBackground").css('height', parseFloat(TmpHeigh)-1);
    }
    else {
        $("#progressIndicatorBackground").hide();
    }
}
```

JS version 3 - changing show and hide function to toggle - This makes the progress loader works on Chrome and IE as well. But the display attubite is always set to block once I start fetching the JSON content. After the content is loaded properly, it doesn't set back to display:none. So I have pre-loader on the page all the time.

```
function progressIndicator(value) {

    if(value) {
        $("#progressIndicatorBackground").toggle();
        var TmpHeigh = $("#progressIndicatorBackground").css('height');
        $("#progressIndicatorBackground").css('height', parseFloat(TmpHeigh)-1);
    }
}
```

I have no clue what to do next and how to fix the problem. I don't care if it is a dirty fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think `toggleClass()` might do the trick, take a look at this [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Waub/2/). Just set a class that hides it with something other then `display:none` and toggle it when you want the load bar to show or when you want to hide it. In my example I just setTimeout instead of animating a loading animation, but hopefully the hide/show method will work regardless.